# ansible.legacy.setup\n - module failed to execute on jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, ansible, gitlab, jenkins-pipeline

I'm using Jenkins to launch a simple Ansible Pipeline (to create a folder on localhost as follow

```
  name: Play1

  hosts: localhost

  become: true

  remote_user: ec2-user

  tasks:

   - name: Create directory

     file:

       path: /home/ec2-user/Newfolder

       state: directory

       group: ec2-user

       owner: ec2-user

       mode: 0700
```

But when i build the pipeline I got this error message:

```
TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"ansible_facts": {}, "changed": false, "failed_modules": {"ansible.legacy.setup": {"failed": true, "module_stderr": "sudo: a password is required\n", "module_stdout": "", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", "rc": 1}}, "msg": "The following modules failed to execute: ansible.legacy.setup\n"}
```

Have you an idea about this error please ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are not providing the `sudo` password, and the `ansible_user` is not already configured for passwordless sudo. Following is the error from the snippet you provided.

```
{"failed": true, "module_stderr": "sudo: a password is required\n",
```

In the playbook, you have provided `become: true` and `remote_user: ec2-user`

```
 become: true

 remote_user: ec2-user
```

So your `ec2-user` is not having permission to become a root user without password being passed.  You can run `sudo -l` command to check what a user can do with his current `sudo` configurations.
If you do not want to change the sudoers file, then simply pass `-K` flag to the playbook while execution to get prompted for the sudo password.

```
-K, --ask-become-pass
```

However, the user `ec2-user` must be in a sudoer file; without it you will an error like the below regardless of supplying `ec2-user` password via `-K`

```
ec2-user is not in the sudoers file
```